# How to reflash Alcatel 5054N Android ROM without android OS on the phone

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

Hello Android Enthusiest forum members,

I have a big problem with a recent ebay purchase of an Alcatel 5054N smartphone that recently became unbootable ; previously I had installed a recovery app by TWRP,and this app had subsequently wiped my android system partition of the Android 5.1.1!!
  My basic question now is how may I "unbrick"(the phone was able to boot to the Alcatel splash shield,but cannot do it anymore... :/ ) this phone without having to take it to a local PC/Cell Phone doctor...
  I have heard of the USB Download Mode Fix recovery dongles(Samsung specific)being sold on ebay,but is there one available (or will work) for an Alcatel 5054N??

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,positive replies which make my day!!

Comment: The one thing you need to look for is a factory image (and how to flash it).

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that you still can boot into recovery mode(TWRP).

Try this if your mobile supports OTG:

1. download a custom ROM or stock ROM that is suitable for your mobile.
2. Copy that ROM into a USB flashdrive.
3. Boot into TWRP recovery mode, connect the flash drive which consists the custom ROM via OTG.
4. Click install, select the custom ROM zip file from the flash drive.
5. Wish for the best.

If your device is not supporting OTG:

1. Since you have TWRP i am assuming that you know how to work with ADB in the command line
2. Connect your device via USB cable to your PC.
3. Go to the folder where you have the platform-tools (android SDK) and open the command line tool from this folder
4. Click `adb devices`. If your device is shown then great.
5. now put the downloaded custom ROM file in this same folder. Comsider renaming the custom ROM file as per your convenience.
6. Now type `adb push <your custom ROM filename> /sdcard/`
7. This command pushes the file to your internal memory root folder.
8. Now open recovery mode again.
9. Select install.
10. Select the custom ROM zip file from the internal storage.
11. And flash it.

Hope any of the methods work.
I